# using css automatically applying different column styles to table columns

Tags: css

In a page I have many HTML tables that have many columns in them. I need to apply different styles on them. All columns will have different width but in tables they will same, by this I mean first column of all tables will be same, same is for second and all columns.

CSS is applied on tables but not on columns, is there a way I just add css classes and I may have not to apply them in html code and they are applied automatically. May be using 
pseudocolumns or any other way ?

Comment: I don't think that you can make it without any server-side programming or using JavaScript.

Comment: How are the tables being generated? Can you add classes while they're being printed? If not, can you use CSS3 selectors? Or only CSS2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're able to use browsers that support CSS `nth-child()`, you can use:

```
tr td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9eASr/1/).

In the above demo I've used `:nth-child(even)` to avoid styling the first of the `td` elements (which contains the row-heading), you could, of course, contain the row heading in a `th` element (which would probably be more semantically correct), or, to style the `odd` columns (or the `odd` `td` elements) but *not* the `:first-child`, the `:not()` selector is available:

```
tr td:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child) {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9eASr/2/).

If you're limited by having to support older browsers, that don't support the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class, you can use the adjacent-sibling selector (though this is less maintainable):

```
td + td, /* styles the second td */
td + td + td + td { /* styles the fourth td */
    background-color: #ffa;
}

td + td + td { /* styles the third td */
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9eASr/3/).

Thoug it'd be easier to style with classes (even if only provided for the `odd` (*or* the `even`):

```
.even { /* styles the cells with the class of 'even' */
    background-color: #ffa;
}

.even + td { /* styles the cell that follows the cell with the 'even' class */
    background-color: #f90;
}
```

You could also use the `colgroup` and `col` elements to define classes for your columns:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="first" />
        <col class="second" />
        <col class="third" />
        <col class="fourth" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Column one</th>
            <th>Column two</th>
            <th>Column three</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row one</td>
            <td>row one, cell one</td>
            <td>row one, cell two</td>
            <td>row one, cell three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row two</td>
            <td>row two, cell one</td>
            <td>row two, cell two</td>
            <td>row two, cell three</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With the following CSS as an example (note there's no reason not to style the other `col` classes, I just chose not to in this demo):

```
.second, .fourth {
    background-color: #ffa;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9eASr/5/).

References:

- [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).
- [`col`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/col).
- [`colgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/colgroup).
- [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-child-pseudo).
- [`:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation).
- [`:not()` compatibility, at Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37).
- [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- [`:nth-child()` compatibility, at Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38).

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 "n-th" selectors but it would not work in older browsers.
So your best solution is to apply the changes in javascript (example with jQuery) after the page has loaded.

```
$(function() {
    $("table tr td:nth-child(n)").css('width', '100px');
});
```

or you can add a class

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(n)").addClass("myWidth1");
```

and in your css

```
.myWidth1{ width: 100px }
```

Make sure the table selector catches all tables.